# Make two dataframes into the same form in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

Say I have a dataframe as:

**DF1**

```
ID   Name  Fruit      Berry  Price
01   Jim   Apple      No     .69
02   Rick  Blueberry  Yes    1.50
```

And another:

**DF2**

```
Name    ID   Price   Berry   Fruit  
Hannah  03   1.20    No      Apple  
Allie   04   .40             Canteloupe
```

So the goal is simple, I just want to rbind these together. But the columns aren't aligned. The real dataframe has like 30 vars, so how could I put these together and reorder the vars accordingly.

**Final df goal:**

```
ID   Name   Fruit      Berry  Price
01   Jim    Apple      No     .69
02   Rick   Blueberry  Yes    1.50
03   Hannah Apple      No     1.20       
04   Allie  Canteloupe        .40
```

Comment: Base R solution could be: `do.call(rbind, list(DF1, DF2))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` which automatically rearranges the columns of second based on the first dataset

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(DF1, DF2)
```

-output

```
#  ID   Name      Fruit Berry Price
#1  1    Jim      Apple    No  0.69
#2  2   Rick  Blueberry   Yes  1.50
#3  3 Hannah      Apple    No  1.20
#4  4  Allie Canteloupe  <NA>  0.40
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Name = c("Jim", "Rick"), Fruit = c("Apple", 
"Blueberry"), Berry = c("No", "Yes"), Price = c(0.69, 1.5)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))


DF2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Hannah", "Allie"), ID = 3:4, Price = c(1.2, 
0.4), Berry = c("No", NA), Fruit = c("Apple", "Canteloupe")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```